# How can I use multiple primary keys to join tables using string_split?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have two or even three primary keys stored in column called "PrimaryKeys". I have to use these keys in a join condition dynamically.

I have tried this and I think I have to use string_split to first split the primary keys from the column and then concatenate them in the join condition. But I am not sure how.

for example, if i have (Id, Person_name, Address) in the column,

I want the sql query to work like:

```
---do stuff
 join on a. Id= b. Id, a.Person_name=b.Person_name, a.Address=b.Address)
```

Can Someone help?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't simply

```
join on a. Id= b. Id **and** a.Person_name=b.Person_name **and** a.Address=b.Address
```

work?

Comment: Hi, i have to this dynamically and maybe string_agg will be used but not sure how

Comment: Please provide a sample of your table data